# Is Perl obsolete?

Tags: perl

Is it worth learning Perl or it is an obsolete language and other languages should be learned instead of it? I would appreciate it if someone could shed light on this subject and give me some advices.

Comment: Opinion based questions are not good for this site.

Comment: I am sorry about this question. I am a beginner and I was trying to optimize my time in learning a good language. Can I change the title to "What is the best language for inline text processing?"

Comment: I have edited the question and the title as well.

Comment: @A2009 Please don't completely change a question when the question has answers. With the new version of the question, the accepted answer made no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Big software isn't really efficient to develop with it, because its oop hasn't the best syntax.

And it hasn't a graph-based garbage collector and has constant (and probably forever lasting) issues with multithreading.

But: for smaller projects it is very beautiful and it can be very efficient.

It was an opinion based question, probably it will be deleted.

Comment: Also, see [Moose](http://p3rl.org/Moose) for a better OOP in Perl.